# c: fgets function reads file but does not print out into terminal

Tags: c, fgets

I have the following program copied from a tutorial about C's `fgets()`. It won't print out the contents of the file into the terminal:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_TEXT 1000

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *file = NULL;
    char str[MAX_TEXT] = "";

    file = fopen("test.txt", "r");

    if(file != NULL) {
        fgets(str, MAX_TEXT, file);
        printf("%s", str);
        fclose(file);
    }
    else {
        printf("cannot read the file\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The only result I get is the letter `t`. The `t` is preceded by a small transparent square.

For your information I am using code::blocks ide on Windows. All the previous code snippets (`fputc()`, `fputs()`...) worked fine.

Comment: What's in the file?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Include the contents of your text file in the question.

Comment: `fgets` is not for printing!

Comment: How do you know it's not printing the contents of the file? Be as precise and specific as you can.

Comment: @David Schwartz The file has this sentence in it: this is a simple test. I know fgets is not meant for printing but I tried to reproduce the contents of the file into the terminal. One other thing: fgetc works fine.

Comment: @omar Again, how do you know that's what is in the file? Be as precise and specific as you can. For example, if you edited it with a program like Notepad, it could be wide characters with an endianness marker and all kinds of other junk. (I looked with <tool> and saw exactly <thing>. Then I checked the size and it was <size>. Would be a start.)

Comment: @David Schwartz Thank you for your hint ! You're right it's Notepad. I just edited it with sublimeText and it's working! if it's not too much to ask: why does Notepad cause this?

Comment: @omar Your program just prints precisely what's in the file without going to any effort to make sense out of it. If the file contains an endianness marker or wide characters, your program just writes it to the terminal byte for byte.

Comment: You don't check the return value from `fgets()`, so there's a chance that the file that was opened is empty — in which case `fgets()` returned a NULL and didn't set anything in `str`.  On the other hand, you do use `char str[MAX_TEXT] = "";` so there shouldn't be unexpected data in the string, so it probably isn't the problem.

Comment: @David Schwartz Thanks again David for the explanation. One last question (I promise): you mentioned in your second comment that you looked with <tool> and saw <thing>. is <tool> an option in notepad. I actually used Notepad++ and I have <tools> as an option.

Comment: No. By "<tool>" I meant you would specify the name of the tool that you used. And by "<think>" you would specify precisely what that tool told you. Describing a problem by telling us conclusions you drew is not nearly as helpful as explaining to us precisely how you drew those conclusion because it's always possible (in this case, certain) that they're wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program makes no effort to figure out what's in the file and present it in a sensible way. So it's not surprising that it makes a mess out of rich text. Modern "text" files are frequently not just raw ASCII characters but contain support for wide characters, endianness markers, and all kinds of other things.

Answer (score -2):

fgets here will execute only once since you are using an if statement and its delimiter is newline (\n) .use a while loop and put fclose statement after the loop to read all lines if thats your goal.Or what you have done is fine for one line but the output depends on the contents of the file.

Comment: The OP is only trying to read one line. Anyway, how does putting `fclose` outside the `if` block help? Why would we want to close the file if `file` is NULL - which it can be if `fclose` is moved outside the `if`. That is clearly not the problem.

Comment: You're right that `fgets()` is only called once, but it would need a loop more than an `if` statement to make it repeat.  The `fclose()` should be outside a loop.  In the question's code, the `fclose()` should not be outside the `if` clause because if the file wasn't opened successfully, the `fclose()` would probably crash.

Comment: Oh yeah if my bad sorry